# How to make Django model field derive its value from another field and be non editable

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I have a use case in which i have created a custom user model in Django rest framework and another model called Book which is created by a user . My models looks like below :

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    AbstractBaseUser,
    BaseUserManager,
    PermissionsMixin)
from django.conf import settings


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None, author_pseudonm=None, **extra_fields):
        """Creates and saves a new user """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')
        if not author_pseudonm:
            raise ValueError("User must have an author pseudo name field")
        user = self.model(email=self.normalize_email(email),
                          author_pseudonm=author_pseudonm, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, author_pseudonm):
        """Creates and saves a new super user"""
        user = self.create_user(
            email=email, password=password, author_pseudonm=author_pseudonm)
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """Custom user model which supports using email instead of username"""
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    author_pseudonm = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["author_pseudonm"]


class Book(models.Model):
    """Custom book model"""
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.IntegerField()
    author = models.CharField(default=user.author_pseudonm)
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

In the book model i have a field called user which is basically a foreign key linking the book created to whoever created that book and another field called author which is basically a field called author_pseudonm from the user model.

I am very new to rest framework and i was wondering if this is the right way to do it .

I want to make the author_pseudonm field automatically populated when a book is created and also to be non editable.

Kindly suggest how i can achieve the same using the rest framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you don't want to duplicate your data this way - you don't need to store `author` in your `Book` model, since it already resides in your `User` model. Whenever you'd need to get author's pseudonym for a given book, you should simply do

```py
book.user.author_pseudonm
```

or if you'd want to reference the column in Django admin or serializers or queryset filters, you can do it using `user__author_pseudonm`

(Note: you seem to have a typo here too `author_pseudonm` -> `author_pseudonym`)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, your problem is that a User can change their pseudonym over time, and that the pseudonym for a particular book should not change when an author changes their pseudonym.

The way that I would do this would be to have a custom `save` function that, given the `User` foreign key, gets the `author_pseudonym` value and inputs that as the `author` field and saves the model.  You can put an `editable=False` flag in the `author` field definition to make sure that nobody edits it by accident in the future.

The following is pseudocode, but I imagine your `save` function for `Book` would look something like this:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    user = self.user
    self.author = user.author_pseudonm
    super(Book, self).save(**kwargs)
```

For the record, the `models` part of DRF and vanilla Django are the same.  You'd achieve this in the same manner regardless of whether you are using DRF because this only has to do with the models.